# Styling pandas based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to color the text or cells of data frame based on the condition. This is the code I have. It works:

```
def Highlight_Majors(val):

    color = 'blue' if val == "Austria" else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

s = df.style.applymap(Highlight_Majors)
s
```

The string "Austria" now appears highlighted in the dataframe.
What if I have more than one countries I need to highlight?

This does not work:

```
def Highlight_Majors(val):

    color = 'blue' if val == "Austria"|"Belgium" else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `in` operator with a set membership test:

```
def Highlight_Majors(val):
    return 'color: %s' % ('blue' if val in {"Austria", "Belgium"} else 'black')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
color = 'blue' if any([val==i for i in ["Austria", "Belgium"]]) else 'black'
```

Comment: @prashanthmanohar _Don't_ use this. It's really slow. I gave it a -1 because it is a bad way of testing. See my answer for details.

Comment: @coldspeed I assume downvote is meant for 'answer not useful' but in this case this approach could be just another way of achieving the same result. Thanks anyway!